# How do I block a thread from starting before an existing thread is finished?

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I am having difficulty in meeting the following requirements:

1. From a JavaFX GUI, enter a filename (in a textfield) and then create an Excel file from the filename using POI.
2. Open the Excel file onthe desktop and put in some data
3. Using the Excel menu, save  the file and close Excel.
4. Get the size of the new Excel file.

My approach is to use three threads to do this:

```
public class ExcelFileCreator {
  
  private static ExcelFileHandler excelFileHandler = new ExcelFileHandler();
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(), "t1");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(), "t2");
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(), "t3");
        
    t1.start();      
    //Create an excel file in the first thread
      try {
        try {
          excelFileHandler.createExcelFile("coggis.xlsx");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {}
        t1.join(5000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        
    t2.start();
    //Open the spreadsheet and put in data. Save it from the Excel menu.
    try {
      t1.join();
      excelFileHandler.openSpreadSheet("coggis.xlsx");  
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        
    t3.start();
        //Now try and get the size of the excel file.
      try {
        t2.join(50000);
          System.out.println("Now get the size of the excel file");    
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        
        //let all threads finish execution before finishing main thread
      try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
            t3.join();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }

}

class MyRunnable implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread started::: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        System.out.println("Thread ended:::"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
    
}
```

The issue I have and need help with when the Excel file opens on the desktop. The third thread, where I want to get the size of  the
Excel file, always starts before I have finished writing data to the Excel file. In other words, I don't know how to stop the third thread
from starting until I have saved and closed the Excel file.

Would be grateful for some help.

Comment: I think the easiest way to run async code in Java is with an ExecutorService (eg a  ThreadPoolExecutor) and to use submit. This submit call returns a Future instance and there are methods on Future interface to check if a task is completed or to wait for it to complete. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your join line outside of the catch clause and remove the integer argument. Join will the wait for the thread to finish untule the code will resume. Add the Join for each of your started thread.

```
 try {
      excelFileHandler.createExcelFile("coggis.xlsx");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {}
    t1.join(5000);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
t1.join(); /// <---- Add this here !
t2.start();
//Open the spreadsheet and put in data. Save it from the Excel menu.
try {
```